# Things scroll by themselves, and in terminal certain text appears by itself ~~~~~

Tags: gnome, firefox, gui, scrolling

I recently partially updated my Ubuntu running on Asus a555la , and I tried to upgrade GNOME also and it worked. After all this certain things started happening:

1. In any window that can scoll, after a certain amount of time scrolling down happens by itself and I can't scroll up at all.
2. The scrolling application instance will be slow to die if I try to close it.
3. It happens with Firefox, PDF viewer, explorer etc.
4. In terminal if I run commands like `sudo apt-get update`, it will work fine, but after it's finished I won't get control back; characters like `[^6....~~~~~` will appear, and I need to push a key to stop it.
5. If I right click, the *New Document* option is not there now.
6. Before, taking a screenshot was very fast but now it's very slow.

My machine is dual-boot, but that was the case before this started happening.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you plug in another keyboard and see if the problem goes away?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a stuck key on your keyboard, or a defective keyboard. Unplug the keyboard to see if the problem stops.

Comment: The Asus A555LA is a laptop.

Comment: @CarlH the keyboard can still be unplugged... not as easy as a desktop machine... but it'll prove that it's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes unplugging worked.

Comment: @gaurav1999 Thanks for the update! Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!